# How to get the label in the collection cell when click a button in the same collection cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, ipad

I have a View Controller with a `UICollectionView`. Each `UICollectionViewCell` has one `UILabel` and one `UIButton`. How can I print the text of each `UILabel` in the `UICollectionView` when clicking the corresponding `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you can subclass your `UICollectionViewCell`, link `UILabel` to corresponding property and create a method for `UIButton` touch. Here is the sample code of this method:

```
@interface MyCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
- (void)cellButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation
- (void)cellButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",_cellLabel.text);
}
@end
```

Besides it, you can look through some guide, e.g. [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12).